# Python DataFrame - Count if condition is met comparing in a second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have a dataframe *UFC_data* with a list of UFC Fights with Fighter A, B, and winner.

```
data = {'fighter_A':['Tony Ferguson', 'Al Iaquinta', 'Robbie Lawler'], 
        'fighter_B':['Donald Cerrone', 'Donald Cerrone', 'Donald Cerrone'],
        'winner': ['Tony Ferguson', 'Donald Cerrone', 'Robbie Lawler']}
UFC_data = pd.DataFrame(data)

+-------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
| Index |   fighter_A   |   fighter_B    |     winner     |
+-------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
|     0 | Tony Ferguson | Donald Cerrone | Tony Ferguson  |
|     1 | Al Iaquinta   | Donald Cerrone | Donald Cerrone |
|     2 | Robbie Lawler | Donald Cerrone | Robbie Lawler  |
+-------+---------------+----------------+----------------+
```

I created a second dataframe *fighter_list* listing each fighter that I want to complete with the number of wins for each fighter

```
+-------+----------------+------+
| Index |    fighter     | wins |
+-------+----------------+------+
|     0 | Tony Ferguson  |      |
|     1 | Al Iaquinta    |      |
|     2 | Robbie Lawler  |      |
|     3 | Donald Cerrone |      |
+-------+----------------+------+
```

Until now I haven't been able to return the number of victories for each fighter

```
for index, row in fighter_list.iterrows():
    fighter_list['wins'][index] = UFC_data['winner'].loc[UFC_data['winner'] == fighter_list['fighter'][index]].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), last replace missing values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and convert values to integers:

```
s = UFC_data['winner'].value_counts()
fighter_list['wins'] = fighter_list['fighter'].map(s).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (fighter_list)
          fighter  wins
0   Tony Ferguson     1
1     Al Iaquinta     0
2   Robbie Lawler     1
3  Donald Cerrone     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the following function:

```
def winCnt(row):
    return UFC_data.winner[UFC_data.winner == row.fighter].count()
```

Then apply it to each row,, saving the result in the target column:

```
fighter_list['wins'] = fighter_list.apply(winCnt, axis=1)
```